# Detecting mouseout of a GtkTreeView row

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, signals

How can I detect when the mouse cursor leaves a GtkTreeView row associated with a GtkListStore model?

Note that the signal "cursor-changed" is not what I am looking for, as it gets emitted as if it is a mouse enter (mouseover) event and I need it to be triggered when the mouse has just left the row instead. However within "cursor-changed" signal and a call of `gtk_tree_view_get_cursor()` I can obtain "the latest mouseovered row" to know which row the mouse cursor has previously entered. So I at least need a way to detect when the mouse cursor leaves some row.

Comment: just by "overing" the mouse you won't get any relevant signal to extract that information.

Comment: @JoséFonte what do you mean? I need a mouse leave (mouseout) detection, because that's when an animation of mine should start. GTK+ seems to not support such signals on this particular widget, but I may be wrong. Few are those who know how much flexible GTK+ could be.

Comment: The problem resides in the fact that the GtkTreeView is made of GtkTreeViewColumns and GtkCellRenderers. These last two aren't GtkWidgets and don't provide any relevant signal to your goal. Using GtkWidget leave-notify-event will only work on the treeview itself, as a whole. There isn't even the concept of row, that information is on the Model. What you could do, and it's a painful endeavor, would be to translate mouse x,y positions and translate that to a cell. Another option would be to use the hover option on selection mode. Let me check with an example.

Comment: If you don't mind to have the row autoselected by hover, you can try using [gtk_tree_view_set_hover_selection](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-set-hover-selection) and keep track of the selected iter/paths then this can be a solution.

Comment: @JoséFonte It is generally a good idea, however my implementation of GtkTreeView does not tolerant such an exotic behavior. It is a click/connect mechanism per se. So perhaps the only idea is to constantly keep track of x/y mouse coordinates and translate them into rows.. which would be destroyer as I don't even know where to start from and as far as I don't see, examples hasn't been published to this day.

Comment: There are some functions to convert coordinates or even go and check GtkTreeView implementation and recreate that same behavior. If you want to do that only on mouse click, then the task would be much easier since you only needed to connect to the GtkTreeSelection changed signal or GtkTreeView row-activated signal. Maybe rethink the UI interaction?

Comment: Check [gtk_tree_view_get_path_at_pos ()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeView.html#gtk-tree-view-get-path-at-pos). Connecting a handler to the treeview motion-notify-event you can have x/y mouse pointer position. There are also some functions to convert coordinates from widget to bin coords and vice-versa. Not ideal but maybe not so difficult :/

Answer (score 0):

Mouseout events normally require widgets to consume a window on the underlying implementation (the Xserver normally sends them when you abandon one window, Windows has another means of signalling them) so in environments where widgets don't use a window (this is quite normal on environments that don't have enough support from the implementation), they must be simulated.  Normally you'll have to check the widget class hierarchy up to the root to see the place where those such events are being emulated, and how, to get an idea on how to deal with them.  Probably you'll have some registering process in the superclasses to allow for a callback to be called on behalf of such events.